# Is there a significant difference in performance between low-level datastore API and JDO/JPA?

Tags: java, performance, google-app-engine, jdo, datastore

Should I expect a noticeable performance boost after switching from JDO/JPA to low-level datastore API? Also, are there any things I should be aware of before switching?

Answer (score 2):

The difference is small, and seem to vary more based on the load on the google servers than the API used.

You can view a realtime test yourself here: http://gaejava.appspot.com/

Answer (score 0):

No - they all use the same underlying RPCs, so they will all have more or less equivalent performance. You certainly shouldn't change your interface of choice based on performance concerns.

Comment: Is that really true?  Sure the underlying RPCs are all the same, but I'm sure JDO adds some of its own overhead, and I would love to understand exactly what JDO is doing but I'm having a hard time building up the motivation to plow through the code of the JDO implementation.  Also, how would you explain this: http://slim3demo.appspot.com/performance/ or this:
http://gaejava.appspot.com

Comment: @tempy There are likely to be performance differences, but they'll be minimal - the network round-trip time, and the disk IO for the datastore _far_ outweighs any extra processing one library or another does on the received data. I wouldn't choose my framework on the basis of this.